# Unusual usage of Git

Tags: git

What is your most unusual usage of Git?

Comment: **From the FAQ (http://superuser.com/faq): Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.**

Comment: This should be community wiki at minimum as there is no true answer to it.

Comment: certainly subjective! but i'm unconvinced: what exactly makes this argumentative?  it's CW, and it might benefit from a little more from the poster, but the feeling i get is that a question should be __subjective AND argumentative__ to deserve immediate killing.  note the faq __does not prohibit__ asking subjective questions.

Answer (score 1):

> What is your most unusual usage of
>   Git?

Early this year, Johannes Schindelin put up an interesting "contest", **UGFWIINI** (*Using Git For What It Is Not Intended*).

Here it is in all its glory: https://public-inbox.org/git/3f4fd2640903030709r6e585d9j57ad3ae08cf38df1@mail.gmail.com/T/#m2a22bb4134907f7a4dfe8a6c1160e13bac1abf45

Answer (score 0):

Temporary commit into a local